# BeautifulSoup can't find a [ a href ] tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

```
page = "http://www.flashscore.com/"
soup =  bs(request.urlopen(page).read(), 'lxml')
typeyourcountry = input("Type in the NAME  or ID of the country you're looking for : ")

a = '/soccer/' + typeyourcountry.lower()

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile(a)}):
    print (link)
    find_urls = re.compile(a+'(.*?)"')
```

OUTPUT:

```
<a href="/soccer/serbia/" onclick="return cjs.dic.get('Helper_Menu').lmenu(167,req_url,1);">Serbia</a>
<a href="/soccer/serbia/super-liga/">Super Liga</a>
```

Even tho there's 3 links that should be outputed I'm only able to find one, is it a dynamic link or has anyone got any ideas to what's happening?
As you can see it on the image, there's 3 links that should be outputed and I can see each of them in the source viewer but got no idea what's going on beyond that, help is appreciated !
Just noticed the JS :

```
onclick="return cjs.dic.get('Helper_Menu').lmenu(167,req_url,1);
```

I guess this script above reveals the information (That I was looking for ), is there any way for me to reveal it with python, make the same request js request and only get that portion of the data or what's the viable solutions?

#### **SUMMARY :** One website has FrontEnd JS script that Reveals particular information

#### How do I implement that kind of request into Python or BeautifulSoup,is there another library that has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the others links are generated with **Javascript**. In fact, if you go to your dev tools in your browser and desactivate JS, you will see that there are only the links that BeautifulSoup is finding.

If you want the others links to appear, you should use **PhantomJS** for example ;)

See ya !

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response. I've added that it's running JS (in the post ) onclick="return cjs.dic.get('Helper_Menu').lmenu(167,req_url,1);
This script, but you haven't really offered me a solution, is PhantomJS that I can somehow implement, can you give me an example or did you just post an observation ?

Comment: The Javascript needs a Web engine to run, and you can use several frameworks to do so in Python. PhantomJS is a fake browser that runs JS, and BeautifulSoup is only a HTML parser. In order to link them, you will need Selenium as well for example, a web scrapper. I think that may be too complicated to me to give you a snippet you just have to run, and that would be counter productive for you as well, but you can find several tutorial on the net : http://techstonia.com/scraping-with-phantomjs-and-python.html is quite nice :)

Comment: Okay so PhantomJS will look into it I'm scared of Selenium for some reason, why can't it have a nice name simple like  Puppy, I swear to God people with their naming these days :D.
Thank you sir, I appreciate it. I know it's a HTML parser I'm just looking for a solution for JS. 
I'm very grateful for the instructions, I just hate it that I have to learn a new library every time I do a new project :D

Comment: Yeah really sorry :/ Tell yourself that Selenium is really easy, and if you have Chrome or Firefox you can use them instead of PhantomJS :)

Comment: Well I appreciate everything you helped me with since you've been so nice in answering questions I'm gonna mark your answer *thumbs up*, hopefully, there won't be a next time but what'd be useful is some reference links, documentation on these, maybe explain it a little bit more so there won't be a need for additional comments, thank you !